# UMVUE for population median of exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

Suppose $ X_1 , \cdots , X_n$  is a random sample from $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ . Then , is it true that the sample median is a uniformly minimum variance unbiased
estimator (UMVUE) of the population median ?

Comment: No, why do you think so? Is the sample median unbiased for the population median,  and is the sample median a complete sufficient statistic?

Comment: The population median is $(\log 2)/\lambda$, and in fact the UMVUE of $\beta=1/\lambda$ is $\bar{X}$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Is there a simple expression for the expectation of the sample median of an exponential distribution? It is easy for $n=1$ but what about larger odd $n$?

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** Following @user10354138's suggestion.

Consider random samples of size $n = 5$ from $\mathsf{Exp}(rate=1/10).$ Thus, $E(X_i) = \mu = 1/\lambda = 10$ and
$MED(X_i) = \log(2) \mu = 6.9315.$  From R statistical software:

```
qexp(.5, lam);  10*log(2)
[1] 6.931472
[1] 6.931472
```

Perhaps see 
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) on 'Exponential distribution' if your
textbook or notes do not have everything you need
to follow theoretical parts of this.

Look at $m = 10^6$ such random samples of size $n = 5$ and
see what happens. By the WLLN simulated quantities should be 'reasonably' close to corresponding 
parameter values. From a simulation with a million samples, one can
expect 2 or 3 place accuracy.

```
set.seed(1234)           # for reproducibility
m = 10^6;  n = 5;  lam = .1
x = rexp(m*n, lam)
MAT = matrix(x, nrow=m)  # m by n matrix each row a sample
a = rowMeans(MAT)        # vector of m mean
h = apply(MAT,1,median)  # vector of m medians
```

We see that $E(\bar X) = 10$ is closely approximated
and that $SD(\bar X) \approx 4.479.$ You can get
easily derive the exact value of $Var(\bar x).$

```
mean(a); sd(a)
[1] 10.00473
[1] 4.479718
```

We know from above that the
population median is $\eta = 6.931472,$ so
the the sample median is not unbiased for $\eta.$

```
mean(h); sd(h)
[1] 7.833585
[1] 4.625242
```

A better estimate of $\eta$ is $\hat \eta = \log(2)\bar X,$ which is based on the sufficient
statistic. The MLE is unbiased and has a smaller SD (hence variance)  than does the sample median. How would you
prove that it is UMVUE?

```
est.h = log(2)*a
mean(est.h); sd(est.h)
[1] 6.934753           # aprx mean of MLE = 6.9315
[1] 3.105104           # SD(MLE) < 4.625242
2*sd(est.h)/sqrt(m)
[1] 0.006204349        # aprx marg of sim err for 6.934
```

Below is a histogram of the simulated distribution of $\hat \eta$ with $E(\hat \eta)$ shown as a
vertical dotted line. Using moment generating functions, it is not difficult to find the density function of the exact distribution of $\hat \eta$ (solid curve), which is related to the gamma distribution of $\bar X.$

[image]